# Select Statement that returns a result where the text characters contains only 0s or only 9s but length doesn't matter

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to write a select statement that returns column A when column B contains '0' or '9' or '00' or '99' or '000' or '999' and so forth. The values are TEXT. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT colA
FROM tab
WHERE REPLACE(colB, '9', '') = ''
   OR REPLACE(colB, '0', '') = '';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=8a13286b4e1f1aede45488b02eccc642)**

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain how = '' interacts with replace()?

Comment: @LightPortal The idea is to replace all 9 with empty string. If original string has only 9 then after replacement it will be ''. Then you only need to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE col like '%9%' or col like '%0%'

Comment: That won't do what OP wants. It'll match strings like `'012'`.